# Is an iframe a proper solution for this issue?

Tags: iframe

I build microsites for a bigger website. Currently, I send the HTML/CSS/JS and it gets embedded on a page. 99% of the time, I need to revise my code because existing CSS and JS on the page screws up my content. The parent page is using XHTML 1.0 Transitional as a doctype, an old version of jQuery (1.2), poorly written styles, etc. whereas my code uses newer scripts and CSS specific for my page.

If I were to load my content in a `<iframe>`, I can avoid these issues entirely. But I'm worried that if I do this, what kind of effect will it have on Google crawling the page. Will Google see the entire page as ONE page, or will it see the `<iframe>` as a "link" and track it as a separate page?

I wish I could override the default CSS styles, as they have some stupid ones like `body a p span div { font-size:18px; font-family:Times; }` but there are too many to override. I know I can use [scoped CSS styles](http://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/) but that seems a bit hacky right now.

So would an iframe be a unacceptable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just searched this up. Apparently iframes are bad for SEO, as you feared. I don't mean to sound rude, but you should have serached yourself before asking about it. I don't know how to fix your CSS/JS issues.

http://www.straightupsearch.com/search-marketing/best-practices/seo_iframes_a_g/

Comment: I did search, and there are multiple posts from earlier this year that Google does look at iframes now. http://www.seroundtable.com/google-iframe-link-14558.html I just want to know if that's sound research.